# C# How to set textbox/label value in static method?

Tags: c#

I tried:

```
System.Web.UI.Page FormPage;
            object FormControl = FormPage.FindControl("lblUserNames");
            object literalControl = FormPage.FindControl("litMessages");
```

But it is throwing an error: "Use of unassigned local variable 'FormPage'"

So how do I set the textbox/label value in a static method?

The whole source:

```
[WebMethod]                                 
        public static void DeleteItem()
        {          
            HttpCookie reader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["roomId"];

            string query = "[Get_Messages]";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomId", reader.Value);

            GetData(cmd);
        }
```

Get data from database to dataset and bind it to div.

```
private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
        {

            int cntr = 0;

            HttpCookie cookieUserName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["userName"];
            string username = cookieUserName.Value;


            System.Web.UI.Page FormPages;
            object FormsControl = FormPages.FindControl("lblUserNames");


            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LinqChatConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds, "Messages");
                        return ds;

                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                        {
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                            int i = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1);

                            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                            {
                                string personName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Username"] == null ? "" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Username"].ToString();
                                string gender = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Sex"] == null ? "" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Sex"].ToString();
                                string message = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Text"] == null ? "" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Text"].ToString();

                                if (cntr == 0)
                                {
                                    if (username == personName)
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("<div style='padding: 10px;text-align:right'>");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("<div style='padding: 10px;'>");
                                    }
                                    cntr = 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (username == personName)
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("<div style='background-color: #EFEFEF;padding: 10px;text-align:right'>");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("<div style='background-color: #EFEFEF;padding: 10px;'>");
                                    }
                                    cntr = 0;
                                }

                                ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)FormControl).Text = "<span style='color: Blue;'><b line-height:22px>" + personName + "</b></span>";
                                string lblUserNames = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)FormControl).Text;
                                //lblUserNames.Text
                                ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)FormControl).Visible = true;
                                //lblUserNames.Visible = true;

                                if (gender.ToLower() == "m")
                                {
                                    if (username == personName)
                                    {
                                        sb.Append(message + "</div>");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("<img src='Images/manIcon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle;' alt=''>  " + lblUserNames + " " + message + "</div>");
                                    }
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    if (username == personName)
                                    {
                                        sb.Append(message + "</div>");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("<img src='Images/womanIcon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle' alt=''>  " + lblUserNames + " " + message + "</div>");
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal)FormsControl).Text = sb.ToString();
                            ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)FormControl).Visible = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)FormControl).Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You either pass the Page... or not use a static method.

Comment: pass the page means?How?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set it?

```
FormPage page = new FormPage();

object FormControl = page.FindControl("lblUserNames");
object literalControl = page.FindControl("litMessages");
```

Comment: where is the 'FormPage()' methode?

Comment: You create it. `FormPage page = new FormPage();`

Comment: @ArmaanAhmed `FormPage()` is not method. its constructor of the FormPage class. i suggest you first learn basics of c# language.

Comment: ^^ Or that. Thanks @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: so in that class what i have to declare?

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary I know basics, just u give proper answer. complete enough.